# iOS Notification - How to manage two app IDs with one P12 file

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, javaapns

I have a notification project that is built for iPhone and iPad. So I have 2 app IDs = 2 applications on the Apple Store.

If I understand the official Apple Guide Lines (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringPushNotifications/ConfiguringPushNotifications.html), I have to create a Push Notification Certificate for a specific App ID. So 2 certificates for notification feature will be created at the end due to the two App IDs I have.

On my server application, I have to manage a .p12 file to send notifications. It works well when I have 1 APNs certificate inside (for example the one that concerns my iPhone app). When I have a .p12 file that contains the 2 APNs certificates (iPhone + iPad), I can't send notifications from server side ! Error is "Failed to deliver notification with error code 8". I'm using Sandbox gateway as I'm using a DEV certificate.

How to manage the 2 app in one .p12 file ? Is it possible ?
I'm using https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns library.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: What makes you think there are multiple certificates in a .p12 file?

Comment: Because I exported my 2 certificates (iPhone + iPad) from my keychain to only one .p12 file

Comment: I'm wondering how you would have gotten the certificates in your keychain to begin with. You'd have the private keys (and possibly the certificate signing requests), but not the certificates unless you manually installed them. You download the certificates (individually) from the member center.

Comment: Indeed, I created 2 APNs certificates in my member center (one for iPhone, one for iPad), then downloaded them, then installed in my keychain, then export the 2 into one .p12 file. P12 file that I'm using in my server application.

Comment: I can't recall  a reference to sending multiple certificates at once written anywhere at the documentation. To think about it, a little effort from all intermediate providers is potentially a huge deal for the central servers performance: imagine larger intermediate providers sending all of their certificate for each notification just because "hey it is easier". This is an interesting idea in the context of sending similar notifications for different apps, but it might be abused too easily. As a final note, perhaps you can get the best response from the official Apple support.